# How to unit test Webservices methods that are called from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, unit-testing

I am experiencing TDD and I need to know how to unit test a webservice that will be calls in js through AJAX.  I have looked up how to mock the ajax call and unit test the webservice individually but I realized what if someone else changes the parameter types or amount in the webservice and completely forget to change the parameters in the ajax call.  Is there any wayto connect the two during the test so that they will be dependent on eachother  because at the moment they would just simple pass the test even if i change the parameters in the webservice even though the ajax call has different parameters then the webservice.

Edit:

The test for JS and C# are separated but that if someone that did not make the test goes in there and edits one of the C# methods and test and forgets about the AJAX call calling it, all the test will pass and noone will know that there was an error till a user clicks on it or goes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing means testing single independent modular unit at a time. So Jquery call and webservice response are two separate units here ( client and server ).

Junit scope is to test a modular unit with all logical inputs. Try to identify all possible requests that would come out of the JQuery and then Mock the request to test Web services.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal shouldn't be to unit test that the AJAX functions within Javascript are working - rather your goal should be to test that your web service exhibits the expected behaviour and that your JavaScript makes the expected AJAX calls with the correct formats.

Most server technologies allow you instantiate your web service class without actually hosting/binding it to anything. You can then call the methods on your service directly via your unit test.

Unit testing your JavaScript can be made easier if you have a solid abstraction around your AJAX calls which can be mocked out using dependency injection.